# Best way to play video frame by frame - zoomed

Tags: objective-c, ios

I need some advice on playing video frame by frame...

Right now I shoot a video and extract all frames using mpmovieplayer thumbnailImageAtTime for each frame.

The video could be zoomed as well.  I am zooming by extracting the frames as mentioned above then resizing and cropping the frames.

This would be great except that thumbnailImageAtTime seems to be very slow.  My videos will be less than 30 seconds long...most of the time only a few seconds and it takes about 20 seconds on iphone 4s to grab 60 frames.  If you think this should be faster I can post the code I am using, but it is pretty straight forward.  I am performing it on a background thread so UI is not affected.

I have been looking at AVFoundation to grab the frames, but have read that it is not exact and I need all 30 fps.

I am really looking for advice on the best way to do this.  I need to be able to use a slider and buttons to move frame to frame backwards and forwards as well as jump to a specific frame.  As I said the video might be digitally zoomed as well.

Should I not extract frames and just use the video file and move from frame to frame?  If so, what is the best way to do this because the mpmovieplayer doesn't seem to allow me to move to an exact frame easily.  Also, if I just use the video file what is the best way to zoom?  Can I go through each frame of an asset and resize and crop it then save back to the video file?  Is this the best way?  Can I achieve everything I want to do using AVFoundation?

I have been trying things for about a week now and I do have everything working extracting the frames using mpmovieplayer...the speed is just unacceptable.  If I could extract the frames very quickly that solution would be the best in my opinion.  I might mention I only have to extract the frames once, not each time the user clicks on the video...if that makes a difference.

I hope this all makes sense and sorry for rambling.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research I am going to go with AVFoundation to play the video frame by frame and not extract the frames.  It works great.